# Log in fails and returns to log in screen

Tags: login, login-screen, gdm

I am running a very nearly fresh Gnome version of 12.10, with no particular tweaks or customisation. I performed an upgrade yesterday using

```
sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get upgrade
```

which completed successfully. After rebooting, I find that I am no longer able to log in - entering my (correct) password brings up a black terminal for a couple of seconds as usual and then returns me to the login screen. So far:

- The guest account can log in fine
- I can log in to a terminal via  Ctrl+Alt+1 etc
- Deleting all my gnome profile entries (.gnome, .gnome2, .gconf, etc) does not help
- A new empty user (created using `$ sudo adduser newguy; sudo passwd newguy`) has the same problem
- `/var/log/syslog` has some odd messages including

  `gdm-simple-slave[1219]: WARNING: Child process -1838 was already dead`

  `WARNING: Failed to give slave programs access to the display. Trying
  to proceed`
- I installed `kde-standard` and had the same problem, so it is not a Gnome issue
- Running `startx` from the terminal available through Ctrl+Alt+1 brings me to a working desktop. If this is allowed to go to screen-saver or is locked, I am unable to wake it (I get an "Authentication Error" message below the password entry field).
- Opening a terminal in a guest session, running `su - myusername` and entering my password and gives the error `setgid: Operation not permitted`

I surmise that something about the Ubuntu login is broken, at least on my system.

Any suggestions will be most gratefully received...

Answer (score 0):

I've just solved this problem for me. It turned out there was probably a problem with certain permissions on my home dir. I remembered changing the permissions on my home dir. Because I have an encrypted home dir I couldn't change permissions on individual files, so I did the following.

`alt f2` to get a tty

Login using normal credentials

`sudo chmod 755 /home`

That solved the problem for me. Now I just have to look for some sane homedir permissions.

EDIT:
Taking it somewhat easier on the permissions

Comment: ... and to revert that dangerous command for `/home`, use: `sudo chmod 755 /home`.

Comment: *(removed previous comment)* What makes you think that a `chmod 755` on `/home` will change? It's in this mode by default on Ubuntu.

Comment: I had been messing with my permissions because of an other issue.